# Setting SuggestionName in SuggestionQuery in RedDog.Search (Azure Search)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

2 years ago I wrote software for the Maywood IL Police department. Part of this software included a google-esque "search as you type" feature. I implemented this using Azure Search and RedDog libraries. Back then they used to incorporate a method called `SuggesterName(string)` that was located in the `SuggestionQuery` class. Now that I made the mistake on update RedDog it appears they did away with this method and have NO documentation available that I can find aside from a couple basic articles (tutorials) written by other devs.

**Does anyone know how to set `SuggesterName` when executing a SuggestionQuery?**

RedDog version: 0.5.1

Here is the short snippet of code if it helps. The commented out line used to be the last method chain call.

```
var client = new IndexQueryClient(_connection);
        var results = await client.SuggestAsync(indexName, new SuggestionQuery(searchTerm)
            .Fuzzy(true)
            .Select("id")
            .Select("FirstName")
            .Select("LastName")
            .Select("FirstAndLast")
            .Select("PermitsOnFile")
            .Select("VehiclePlatesOnFile")
            .Select("VehicleMakeModelYear")
            .Select("VehicleIds")
            .SearchField("FirstName")
            .SearchField("LastName")
            .SearchField("FirstAndLast")
            .SearchField("PermitsOnFile")
            .SearchField("VehiclePlatesOnFile")
            .Top(10));

        //SuggesterName("quicksearch"));
```

Comment: Looking at the source code on github I see there is a property called `SuggesterName` on `SuggestionQuery` class but on the nuget package there is not. Guess I'll compile the source code and use that. Damn developers! arg!

Comment: Please note that RedDog.Search is a third party SDK not supported by Microsoft. Here is the official SDK from the Azure Search team: https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Search

Are there features we could add to the SDK that would make it easier to migrate?